# How to find unused variables in a template?

Tags: twig

Legacy code, is preparing a lot of data, and sometimes it is not used in rendered TWIG template.

Is there a way to know, what wasn't use during rendering process?

Will be nice to see, or force to render all other data, that was not touched.

PS: my idea is just get rid of that not used things, and will be nice to find and see them, with not digging to millions lines of code

PS2: twig is used as separate composer package, and is not connected neither Symphony or Drupal

Comment: Nope, `twig` has no way of tracking which variables are rendered/used. Not by default though. You could try and dump all the variables with `{{ _context|keys|dump }}`. Will only work if you enable the [debug extension](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/dump.html) though